# Magento1 - Show catalog products only to logged-in customer

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, products

I want to show product1 is only to the logged in customers and this product is not visible in **STORE** view.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**First** you have to **create one attribute to product for its visibility condition**.

use `catalog_product_collection_load_before` **event** to filter the product collection based on user is logged in or not.

take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19849845/7089203) for more detail.

probably not best solution but can be helpful to start.